# vssadmin don't want reconize shadowID (Invalid option value)

Tags: powershell, snapshot

I'm wondering why my Shadown ID of a snaphot is not reconize when i want to select or delete it...

**Context**

I have created my snapshot with this:

```
$snapshot = Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_ShadowCopy -MethodName Create -Arguments @{Volume='D:\' }
```

And that the output:

```
$snapshot

ReturnValue ShadowID                               PSComputerName
----------- --------                               --------------
          0 {5905C83A-58ED-408F-816B-AF61881199FB}
```

But when i want to select it or delete it, vssadmin tell me there is an error...

```
vssadmin list shadows /shadow={5905C83A-58ED-408F-816B-AF61881199FB}
```

Output :

```
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

Error: Invalid option value.
```

**EDIT**

I have try omitting the curly braces, pass the value by variable ($Snapshot.shadowID)... Nothing new

Comment: Try omitting the curly braces, eg. `vssadmin list shadows /shadow=5905C83A-58ED-408F-816B-AF61881199FB`

Comment: Already did and i have the same issue... I tried to pass the value by variable with something like "/Shadow=$snapshot.shadowID" but it's the same...

Comment: That's definitely _not_ going to produce a valid argument, you want `vssadmin list shadows /shadow="$($snapshot.ShadowId)"` or `vssadmin list shadows /shadow=$snapshot.ShadowId`

Comment: Nice thank you ! vssadmin list shadows /shadow="$($snapshot.ShadowId)" work well, i don't know why the others answer don't work ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to pass the GUID without the `{}` curly braces. The default string representation will do:

```
vssadmin list shadows /shadow="$($snapshot.ShadowId)"
```

Comment: For information, just the ShadowID without curly braces have the same issue but when we pass by a variable with the syntaxe above it work (and this syntaxe return the shadowID with curly braces). Thanks Microsoft oO

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will work, but the reason is wrong.

You need to pass the GUID WITH curly braces wrapped in "". The default string representation will do:

```
vssadmin list shadows /shadow="$($snapshot.ShadowId)"
```

Also:

```
vssadmin list shadows /shadow="{e9c09c8b-b0c4-4546-bc23-9b8936890a5d}"

vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

Contents of shadow copy set ID: {41e9241c-4a2f-499b-9361-febd476ec973}
   Contained 1 shadow copies at creation time: 10/31/2023 1:28:52 PM
      Shadow Copy ID: {e9c09c8b-b0c4-4546-bc23-9b8936890a5d}
```